# Exception class naming wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, exception, wsdl, wsimport

Web Service Newbie Question:

`wsimport` generates two classes: `MyException` and `MyException_Exception` for my wsdl-File, but `MyException` does not extend `Exception`. How to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it. The `wsimport` tool generates

- one class for the xml type and
- one class for the Exception.

This results in a name collision. Therefor the `_Exception` prefix is added to the wanted class.

The solution is to give the xml type a different name.

This is done by annotating the server-side class:

```
@XmlType(name = "UnknownDomainExceptionType", namespace = "...")
public class MyException extends Exception {
   ...
}
```